# Unable to know know the status of upload to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda to upload content to s3 bucket.
Below is the code I have written.
`

```
const result = s3.putObject(params).promise();
   result
     .then(function (data) {
       console.log(`File uploaded successfully');
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
       console.log(`Upload failed: ${err}`);
     });
```

`
All required permissions are given. During debug also, I am not able to hit the break point for the console.log statements. In output also nothing is logged.

Please help me to resolve.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code.  You're mixing quote marks on your, "file uploaded successfully", line.

Comment: Quote issue is a typoerror in question. In code, it is correct. But still the console.log is not executed and breakpoint is not hit at console statements.